# Reporting services 2008 textbox labels

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

Im creating a report in RS2008.

Everytime I create a textbox and write an expression, instead of watching the expression text after I change focus of the element I get the following tag: `<<Expr>>`.

I'm used to creating reports on RS2005 and if in a textbox I wrote `="Hello"`, for example, once I change focus it will display `="Hello"`  not `<<Expr>>`.

Its probably a setting but I can't find how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can change this - it's by design in SSRS 2008.

I would say the reasoning behind it is that you can now have multiple placeholders in one Textbox and it's easier to represent with multiple `<<Expr>>` values:

[image]

For text and basic field values, these will not have `<<Expr>>` displayed.

If you change basic text from `="Hello"` to just `Hello` that's what will be displayed in the designer:

[image]

And an expression like `=Fields!val1.Value` will be displayed like this in the designer:

[image]

It's jarring at first but you get used to it.